# Understanding the JS code while setting up redis with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, redis

I was trying to understand caching in NodeJS using redis.

In the lecture, the instructor told that best place to setup caching would be just before exec function in mongoose.

So in order to do that he did

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const exec = mongoose.Query.prototype.exec;
//Redis logic
mongoose.Query.prototype.exec = function () {
 console.log("i am here") 
 return exec.apply(this, argument);
}
```

**1st:** What will classify `mongoose.Query.prototype.exec;` as? value type or reference type? Because if it is a reference type then when we change  `mongoose.Query.prototype.exec = function` then shouldn't its value change as well?

**2nd** I am unable to comprehend this line here `return exec.apply(this, argument);` Can someone explain this in stretch i.e this in apply points to where? and he is passing argument `(this, argument);` where does that Argument come from?

Can someone please help me out by answering both the above question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What will classify mongoose.Query.prototype.exec; as? value type or
>   reference type? Because if it is a reference type then when we change
>   mongoose.Query.prototype.exec = function

`exec` is of reference type, but it is assigned the value of another reference variable `mongoose.Query.prototype.exec`. You can think of it like this : `mongoose.Query.prototype.exec` is itself pointing to an object (a Function object) in memory, and now after the assignment, `exec` is also pointing to the same object - in other words, the memory address of the object is copied (by value) from `mongoose.Query.prototype.exec` to `exec` during assignment. So the value of the variable `mongoose.Query.prototype.exec` itself i.e. the memory address stored in it, can be changed without affecting the other variable `exec`. They both will just end up pointing to two different objects.

> Can someone explain this in stretch i.e this in apply points to where?

In this case, it'll be the object on which this function will be invoked i.e. the `Query` instance.

> and he is passing argument (this, argument); where does that Argument come from?

Unless there is some code you missed to copy paste in the question, `argument` appears to be a typo. He was probably referring to the built-in object `arguments` which is accessible inside every function and consists of the arguments passed to the function. Here is a [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

At a high level, what the instructor is trying to do is to override the built-in behavior of the function `Query.exec()` to add some of his own custom processing. He first creates a "backup" of the original function, then points Query.exec to his custom function which adds the custom processing (the log statement) and then hands over control to the backup i.e. proceed with built-in behavior. Whoever invokes exec() on a Query instance after this point will see the overridden functionality - first a log statement, then built-in behavior of `exec()`

Comment: amazing answer. I will continue watching probably he will talk about argument as we move on or I will run the code without passing arguments to see if it works as intended. 
Can you please elaborate more on `apply` part?

Comment: @KuchBhi Not sure if I can explain it any better than the great [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply). Please let me know if you have questions in that doc.